# Lyapunov exponent for simple functions

Tags: functions

**Context:**

---

We know that $\cos(x)$ if taken recursively on itself, converges to the [Dottie number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html), which is the function's stable fixed point then.

On the other hand, for a function like $f(x)=3x$, keeps diverging if taken on itself.

On the other hand, we know that calculating [Lyapunov's exponent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent) $\lambda$ helps to find out about such behavior of functions.

Meaning of exponent's sign:

[image]

[image]

$\lambda$ for 2nd picture should be positive, mistake in picture...

---

**Question:**

- Can one analytically calculate and show that for example $\lambda$ for $\cos(x)$ is negative, and $\lambda$ is positive for $3x$ , as expected?

Comment: Source of image: http://hypertextbook.com/chaos/43.shtml

Comment: Are you aware that simply the definition implies that the Lyapunov exponent for the $3x$ function is $\log3\gt0$? And a similarly direct computation is available for the cosine case...

Comment: @Phonon ?? Anything not zero.

Comment: @did haha right ok :)

Comment: @Did thanks for the comment, but I don't see how you get it... for either case using formula on wiki, I'm stuck at these limits (putting $\partial Z_0=1$): $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\ln(-sint dt)}{t}$ and for the other one $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\ln(3 dt)}{t}$ ... how to proceed? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for either case using formula on wiki, I'm stuck at these limits (putting $\partial Z_0=1$): $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\ln(-sint dt)}{t}$ and for the other one $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\ln(3 dt)}{t}$

Sorry? What is, in the second case, say, $3dt$ when $t\to\infty$? And why put $\partial Z_0=1$, as you say, when the limits are considered for $\delta Z_0\to0$?

What does the WP page you link to, actually say? One considers a dynamical system, that is, in continuous time $Z'(t)=f(Z(t))$ or in discrete time $Z_{n+1}=g(Z_n)$, and one is interested in

> *the speed at which trajectories starting from two different points diverge one from the another when the time is large*.

To make this precise in the discrete setting, one considers two starting points $x$ and $y$ and the systems $Z^x_{n+1}=g(Z^x_n)$, $Z^x_0=x$, and $Z^y_{n+1}=g(Z^y_n)$, $Z^y_0=y$. If $Z^x_n-Z^y_n$ behaves roughly as $\mathrm e^{n\lambda}$, then one calls $\lambda$ the Lyapunov exponent.

Of course, more care is needed to define this rigorously: one actually fixes some $x$ and one considers the limit $y\to x$, then, if $|Z^y_n-Z^x_n|/|y-x|\to k_n(x)$ when $y\to x$ and if $k_n(x)=\mathrm e^{n\lambda(x)+o(n)}$ when $n\to\infty$, then $\lambda(x)$ is the Lyapunov exponent at $x$. Thus, $$\lambda(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\lim_{y\to x}\log\left(\frac{|Z^y_n-Z^x_n|}{|y-x|}\right).$$
This may seem abstruse but the idea is simple, so let us see what happens when $g:z\mapsto3z$ (your second case). Then $Z^x_n=3^nx$ for every $x$ and every $n$ hence $$\frac{|Z^y_n-Z^x_n|}{|y-x|}=3^n,$$ for every $y\ne x$, in particular $k_n(x)=3^n$ for every $n$ and indeed $\lambda(x)$ exists for every $x$ and $\lambda(x)=3$.

Likewise, if $g:z\mapsto\cos(z)$ and $x=\cos(x)$, that is, $x\approx0.739$ is the Dottie number, then, for every $y$, $Z^y_n=\cos^{\circ n}(y)$ hence $k_n(x)=|(\cos^{\circ n})'(x)|$. For every $z$, $$(\cos^{\circ n})'(z)=(-\sin z)(-\sin(\cos z))\cdots(-\sin(\cos^{\circ (n-1)} z)),$$ in particular $k_n(x)=(\sin x)^n$ hence $\lambda(x)=\log\sin x\approx-0.395$.